# Gulp task failing only with gulp.watch()

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have written a gulp task which finds `.json` files in a directory, assumes there is a corresponding `.atlas` file, and inlines them into my JS project inside one object:

```
gulp.task('spine', function() {

    var fs = require('fs');

    function parseAtlas(atlasPath) {
        var atlas = fs.readFileSync(atlasPath, 'utf8').replace(/[ ]/g, '');
        return JSON.stringify(atlas);
    }

    return gulp.src(config.src+'spineData/*.json')
        .pipe(tap(function(file) {

            var path = file.path.split('/');
            var fullName = path.pop();
            var name = fullName.split('.')[0];
            path = path.join('/')+'/';

            var atlas = parseAtlas(path+name+'.atlas');
            var json = file.contents;

            file.contents = Buffer.concat([
                new Buffer("var app = (function(mod) { mod.pixi.spineData['"+name+"'] = {\n"),
                new Buffer("atlas: "+atlas+",\n"),
                new Buffer("json: "+json+"\n"),
                new Buffer("}; return mod; })(app || {});")
            ]);

        }))
        .pipe(uglifyJS('data.min.js', {
            outSourceMap: true,
            basePath: config.dest,
            sourceRoot: '/'
        }))
        .on('error', util.handleErrors)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));

});
```

The task works as expected except when using `gulp.watch()`. An external program changes `file.json` and the task fails with:

```
gulp-uglifyjs - UglifyJS threw an error
error: Unexpected token: punc (})
```

I am guessing it's something to do with `gulp.watch()` being called before the `.json` file is completely written by the external program. These are fairly big files - currently at around 6000 lines.

I've tried adding a delay (using `gulp-wait`) both before the `tap` pipe and the `uglify` pipe but still always fails with `gulp.watch()`.